# Put timestamp in Elasticsearch cluster as type date from Appsync

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-appsync, aws-iot

I'm trying to store a thing shadow from IoT into AWS Elasticsearch through Appsync and I'm wondering how I can store the timestamp as a date type in Elasticsearch. It keeps showing up as a number and I can't find where to put the ES mapping. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up ES via AWS ES: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html

Similar to ES itself: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-agent/issues/108